# Error in table rotation

Tags: tables, rotating

I have a table that I want to rotate. I checked on Stack Exchange and using a package `rotating`

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{table}[hbt!]
  \vspace{-0.1in}
  \centering
  \caption{Routing Function Table for HopliteRT. PE injection has lowest priority and will stall on conflict. PE$\rightarrow$E + W$\rightarrow$S is not supported to avoid an extra select signal driving the multiplexers and doubling LUT cost by preventing fracturing a 6-LUT into 2$\times$5-LUTs.}
  \label{routing-table-rt.tbl}
  \begin{tabular}{llll}
    \hline
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{{\bf Mux select}} & {\bf Routes} & {\bf Explanation} \\ 
    \cmidrule{1-2}
    {\bf sel1} & {\bf sel0} &  & \\
    \midrule
    0 & 0 & W$\rightarrow$E + N$\rightarrow$S  & Non-interfering \\
    0 & 1 & W$\rightarrow$S + N$\rightarrow$E  & Conflict over S (Not supported in Hoplite)\\
    1 & 0 & PE$\rightarrow$E + N$\rightarrow$S & No W packet \\
    1 & 1 & PE$\rightarrow$S + W$\rightarrow$E & No N packet (Not possible in Hoplite) \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

But I am getting an error message `LaTex Error: Not in outer par mode`

Comment: A `table` environment can't be used inside of `sidewaystable`. So remove the `table` environment.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`rotating` documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/rotating):

> The environments `sidewaystable`and`sidewaysfigure`introduce landscape-form floating `tables` and `figures`, respectively.

As such `sidewaystable` is intended to replace the `table` environment if you want to get a rotated floating table and nesting these floating environments will result in the described error. If you remove the `table` environment from your code, it will work as expected.